# CSS: 100%-height/width DIV inside a bordered div creates vertical, but not horizontal scrollbars

Tags: html, height, border, css

Hello and thanks for listening. This is not an urgent question for me, I'm just curious about why the following code does what it does. I wanted to have a border (or margin) around the visible page, and a nested DIV where "100% height and width" refers to the inside of that border (for further nesting).

```
<html>
  <body style='height:100%; width:100%; margin:0;'>
    <div style='border:5px solid green'>
      <div style='height:100%; width:100%;'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously I (think to) know the box-model and what 100% means (here: the content box of the first DIV), and I know how to solve the problem using absolute positioning.

But what I don't understand: In Chromium as well as in Firefox, why do I get a *vertical* scrollbar but no *horizontal* one? It looks like the 100% height in the second DIV does not take into account the content box of the first DIV (respecting the 5px border), but rather the whole BODY content box. For 100% width however, things work as I thought they would - no horizontal scrollbar appears.

Can someone enlighten me? Is this historic browser behaviour?

**EDIT** after FredWilson's answer: If you give the BODY absolute dimensions 'height:100px; width:100px' the result stays the same: The vertical border extends the 100px height, but the horizontal border gets included. I try to reread the small print of [the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) but so far, I don't see any difference between height and width handling.

*Left: BODY tag in Firebug; right: First DIV tag in Firebug.*
[image: BODY tag in Firebug]    [image: First DIV tag in Firebug]

Comment: Can't you set the border property for the body element? I wouldn't know because I've never used it that way.

Comment: No, that pushes both height and width to be larger than the current window size. I know there are workarounds, I'd just like to understand why the above snippet gets interpreted like it does :-)

Comment: Like I said below, in your first image, you have the body rendering @ 100px.  In the second image, you have the inner div pushing the outer div height to 100% (of the body).  The browser still computes the borders and renders the outer div 10px outside of the body.  Might not make much sense, but the DOM is funny like that.

Comment: I fully agree with you, just wanted to add that this also happens with "small" DIVs and BODYs. (If you replace the BODY dimensions with an additional DIV, same thing happens.) Now I just wonder whether this difference between height and width handling is just a "common behaviour" exposed by different rendering engines, or is it defined somewhere in the specifications?

Comment: I have never found it in the specs, and believe me, I've looked!  The way I read the spec, we should get horizontal scroll bars in this case as well.  It's interesting how we can get a div to overflow the BODY element but not all that surprising.

Comment: @cato_minor: I fixed up your links for you.

Comment: Just a follow up, the width calculation relies on quirksmode to work in this case. Setting a strict doctype will create a new set of issues, such as needing to set html to 100% and making sure that 100% height is on every DOM element in the chain. Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see how this is intentional is to open Chrome's Developer Tools and inspect the BODY and DIV tags.  Note that chrome shows the BODY width and the div width to be 297px in my example.  However, the BODY height is 275px and the DIV is 285px.

[image: Showing Body]
[image: Showing Div]

What this tells us, and is no surprise, is that Chrome calculates the border setting and removes that space from somewhere else in the box.  At the same time, Chrome respects the height without question which is why you get a vertical scrollbar.

I can't cite any official sources, but this has been my experience. Chrome & Firefox assume that width:100% is intended to only fill the viewport and so they adjust the box content appropriately.

However, since there are so many other variables to consider for height, and since height is a difficult thing to calculate in any sense, both browsers fall back to the exact CSS definitions.

Technically, both browsers *should* produce a horizontal scroll bar with your code.  That they do not is most likely because the vendors did what they thought the developer probably intended in as many cases as possible.

Edit:
TL;DR The width calculation relies on quirksmode to work in this case. Setting a strict doctype will create a new set of issues, such as needing to set html height and width to 100% and making sure that 100% height and width is on every DOM element in the chain. You will also have both scrollbars since the DOM will be respected.

Comment: Nice explanation. I would rather have things do what I *said* to do, not what they think I intended. If I want to do **X** but I say it wrong I want it to *be* wrong so I learn the right way.

Comment: Nice screenshots, thank you! Firebug shows me the same. But when you change the BODY's dimensions to absolute values, say, 100px width and 100px height, an area much less than your window size, the inside DIV will have a content box of 90x100. The BODY will still have 100x100 but, as Firebug shows, it won't cover the whole area. Will see how I can upload a screenshot like yours...

Comment: @cato_minor - Stackoverflow's editor has an image icon.  Just click that and upload your image from your disk. I think that even when you set up the body like you have, the same issue still applies. The body is rendering @ 100px and the outer div (with the border) is filling that 100% + the borders for a total of 110px in this case.  Firefox & Chrome respect vertical div settings.

Comment: my account is too fresh, I'm not yet allowed to use that icon :-)